# Extracting unequal number of rows by group in r

Tags: r, dataframe, row, extract

I've a two variable data frame grouped by Shape and would like to extract the first n number of rows (n is different for each level of the grouping variable)  for each group. I tried some of the dplyr and data.table functions but they seem to work only for equal number of rows.

```
Data <- data.frame(Shape = c("R", "R", "R", "C", "C", "T", "T", "T", "T"), Area = c(35, 30, 25, 32, 28, 40, 35, 33, 31))
```

I would like to get the first 2 Rs, the first C and the first 3 Ts. The expected outcome:

```
Out <- data.frame(Shape = c("R", "R", "C", "T", "T", "T"), Area = c(35, 30, 32, 40, 35, 33))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `group_split` into a `list` of `data.frame` with the 'Shape' column and then pass the restriction 'n' in `map2` to `filter` the number of rows accordingly

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
Data %>% 
  group_split(Shape = factor(Shape, levels = unique(Shape))) %>% 
  map2_dfr(., c(2, 1, 3), ~ .x %>%
                             filter(row_number() <= .y))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  Shape  Area
#* <fct> <dbl>
#1 R        35
#2 R        30
#3 C        32
#4 T        40
#5 T        35
#6 T        33
```

---

Or another option is to have a column 'n' by passing a named vector and then grouped by 'Shape' do the `filter`

```
Data %>%
    mutate(n = setNames(c(2, 1, 3), unique(Shape))[as.character(Shape)]) %>% 
    group_by(Shape) %>%
    filter(row_number() <= n[1]) %>%
    select(-n)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response @akrun! That's what I wanted.

Comment: @akurn - I was wondering if the approach works for multiple grouping variables instead of just one - let's say 3 grouping variables. Thank you.

Comment: it would  you just need to add those variable in group by

Comment: @BMM If you have 'n' number of groups, then it is better to have a key/val dataset i.e. `keydat <- crossing(Shape = unique(Data$Shape), grp1 = unique(Data$grp), grp2  = unique(Data$grp2))` and then create the column 'n' for those combinations and do a join as in Georgery's post

Answer (score 2):

A little more complicated than akrun's version, but maybe easier to read:

```
library(tidyverse)

numberRows <- tibble(Shape = c("R", "C", "T")
        , firstRows = c(2,1,3))

Data %>%
    left_join(numberRows, "Shape") %>%
    group_by(Shape) %>%
    slice(1:(mean(firstRows)))
```

Comment: Hi @Georgery - I tried your approach but for some reason I'm not getting the expected outcome in the question. I get 2 Rs, 2 Cs, and 2 Ts instead of 2 Rs, 1 C and 3 T. I was going to use your approach for a more complex problem (Multiple grouping variables). Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you get time to look at my question? Thank you.

Comment: If I have multiple grouping variables and multiple groups have the same firstRows values, do I still group it by firstRows or by the grouping variables and use the same approach. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes. If you have multiple grouping variables you need to include them 1. in the `numberRows` dataframe 2. in the `by = ` parameter of the `left_join` and 3. in the `group_by`.